# href=“tel:” with + in the middle of tel

Tags: html

I'm trying to use `href="tel"` in tag `<a>` with tel like `**61*+70123456789#`. But the plus symbol removing on mobile devices. Looks like `+` can be only at the start of the tel.

Trying to use `%2B` instead of `+`, but it still hiding.

```
<a href="tel: **67*+70123456789%23">**67*+70123456789#</a>
```

Comment: of course the plus symbol can only be used at the start, this is not a valid telephone what are you trying to do?

Comment: `**67*+70123456789#` is not a valid phone number. `+70123456789` might be valid. The country code comes after the plus sign, not before.

Comment: I think this is against the convention if not the standards, that is why browsers refuse it, I don't know the standard here but I don't see plus sign in the middle of telephone numbers, just use normal 00

Answer (score 1):

The `tel:` prefix on a HTML link tag (`<a>`) is used to compose a phone number. However, phone numbers cannot have a "+" symbol, except at the beginning to indicate the international country code, which is why you cannot do what you are trying.

For more information, check at the [E.164 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164) about phone number formatting.